# using malloc in main but accessing outside main

Tags: c, arrays, scope, malloc

is there a way to define a "buffer" using dynamic memory in "main" fuction, but using it outside "main" in another function
i.e.
i have an array i allocate memory to "buffer" by "malloc" in "main" as follow

```
int main()
{
uint32_t *buffer = malloc( array_size * sizeof *buffer);


}
```

but I have to initialize values outside main

```
void fun(uint32_t data)
{
buffer[0] = data;
...

}
```

infact in my case data is coming from camera at run time

i also tried to use "malloc" at global scope but it did not worked

Comment: You simply pass the pointer as a parameter to this function.

Comment: pass the *buffer to a function and form that function try to modify it. it will work. and what error are you getting when you are using malloc in global space ?

Comment: Please put some effort into your questions (no punctuation is a bad sign), I can't read it.

Comment: You're mixing things. You don't define `malloc`, you define `buffer`. The function `malloc` is already defined for you.

Comment: i am getting error that "initializer element is not a compile-time constant" @Nihar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple and naive way:

```
uint32_t *buffer;

void fun(uint32_t data)
{
    buffer[0] = data;
    ...

}

int main()
{
    buffer = malloc( array_size * sizeof *buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass that variable as argument to a function.

Like this,

```
void fun(uint32_t data,uint32_t* buffer){ 
 // do your work
}
```

Include the header file `stdlib.h`. Declare the prototype of that function like this.

```
void fun(uint32_t,uint32_t*);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define an global  uint32_t point, like`uint32_t *buffer1`,then let `buffer1=buffer` in main and use `buffer1` in other function

Answer (score -1):

Create a class that the fun function will belong to. Have that class fill the buffer with a class method. Then create an instance of that class in main. Let that instance do the work, then delete it.